# Deny favicon request

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I know if I create favicon and set appropriate expire headers browser will cache it and stop requesting it.

My question is how do I stop browser requesting favicon when there is no icon file for a limited time (i.e. 30 days)?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot stop anyone from making any requests. You can only decide what to do with the requests you receive.

Nothing you do will stop me from opening a connection to port 80 on your server and asking for the favicon.

But if you are just talking about ordinary folk on common browsers, you should just give 'em a favicon so they stop asking. Make a white square or something, doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I can't stop you making the request, and I don't want to stop you, I just wanted to let your browser know after first request that "there is no favicon, come back in month" as with caching - "here's my favicon, ask me if I have a new one in a month".